# Highcharts Overflowing the parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

So my issue is pretty weird, I have multiple high charts on my bootstrap page, they were working fine. Recently i observed that the size of the high chart is overflowing the size of its parent container.

But when I open console (Or when I resize browser window), the high charts again fits in.

What can cause this behaviour? Did high charts made any size changes in the production?

Rest everything on the page is as good as it was.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838758/highcharts-graph-width-is-incorrect-when-scrollbar-is-present-in-bootstrap-flui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516284/highcharts-item-width-not-100-in-carousel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206631/why-are-bootstrap-tabs-displaying-tab-pane-divs-with-incorrect-widths-when-using

Answer (score 3):

Its general issue asked many times and I also had same issue in starting.
make your div's position relative and put following css for highcharts container

```
.highcharts-container
{
 position: absolute;
  width: 100% !important;
 }
```