# Highcharts redraw not redrawing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've been playing with `Highcharts` **(v3.0.10)** for a week on a webpage and can't get my charts redrawn when printing the page. The thing is that I use a dark background color for my charts, but when printing, I'd like to **change it to white**. For accomplishing that, I need to `redraw()` my charts after changing the `backgroundColor` property. The thing is that when I do that, the background color changes on the printing preview, **but data is gone**, it doesn't get redrawn for some reason.

**Before** trying to change background colors, I've been doing some reworking with the container div sizes and call `reflow()` for the charts to adjust to an A4 page, and it worked perfectly when previewing the print page: Containers were the size I wanted them to be and charts reflowed successfuly to their new size.

Problems begin when I wanted the background to turn white and added the `redraw()` method on the callback triggered when user tries printing the page. Containers still `reflow()` correctly and background changed to white, but **data is missing on the charts.**

I've created a **sample fiddle** which you can [review here](https://jsfiddle.net/eae72xuw/7/). It works on Chrome and Firefox (I mean you can reproduce the problem).  For previewing this fiddle I provided, just go and try to **print the fiddle page** with your browser, so the page printing preview window comes up.

Added some screenshots for Firefox printing page preview and data dissappearing [on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFdEw.jpg).

Also note the `Highcharts` version I'm using: `3.0.10`. It's not the latest but can't get any higher with the current license I own.

---

**Some code and stuff**

Print handler and code executed when user tries to print:

```
/** Chrome **/
        if (window.matchMedia) {
            var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
            mediaQueryList.addListener(function (mql) {
                if (mql.matches) {
                    resize();
                } else {
                        unresize();
                }
            });
        }
    // Firefox
  if (window.onbeforeprint !== undefined && window.onafterprint !== undefined) {
            window.onbeforeprint = function() {
                resize();
            }
            window.onafterprint = function() {
                unresize();
            }
        }

  var originalBackground = '#333';
  function resize(){
      // Do some transformations to fit an A4 page that 
      //are not the matter of this question
      // ......
      //......
      // Loop through all containers (only two but anyways...)
      // and apply changes
      $('.graph-container').each(function(i,e){
        let chart = $(e).highcharts();
        chart.options.chart.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
        // Create new chart with background color
        $(e).highcharts(chart.options);
        // Force redraw 
        $(e).highcharts().redraw();
    });
  }      
  function unresize(){
    $('.graph-container').each(function(i,e){
            let chart = $(e).highcharts();
      // Revert background to original color #333
      chart.options.chart.backgroundColor = originalBackground;
      $(e).highcharts(chart.options);
      $(e).highcharts().redraw();
    });
  }
```

Comment: you can get help from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100011/highcharts-redraw-vs-new-highcharts-chart

Comment: @AwaisRafique Thanks, I had looked at that question before but he struggles with changing the data series dinamically, for me, data is the same, I only want to change the chart's background color, data remains the same. I don't think I should pass the same data again just for the `setData` method to force redraw. I mean, maybe it works, but I don't believe that's the optimal solution :(

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using ? I just installed firefox on my Macbook and ran your fiddle example and it worked. It changed its background to white and the data remain the same

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/J56hm/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=J56hm

Comment: @jprivillaso `51.0.1`32bit on Windows

Comment: @JorgeGRC The same here. 64bit and It's working for me. The problem is that when you click on print the data is gone right ?

Comment: @AwaisRafique thanks for your Fiddle Awais, but what I'm trying to accomplish is change background color when user previews the printing page, I'm not trying to change background color using a button. Background color should change when user clicks on "Print page" using the browser, you get a preview page for whatever the printer is going to print, and there, background should become white and plot all data correctly, not sure if I'm explaining myself correctly

Comment: @jprivillaso yep, chart changes background color but data is gone, it isn't plotted.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/s2zbjf0s3/

Comment: @jprivillaso yep but that's not the preview page, this is what I mean when I  refer to th printing preview page: http://imgur.com/efF2VIR. Another screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/2ozcS

Comment: Oh right right. Sorry, I wasn't understanding right the question

Comment: I'm updating the fiddle with chrome handlers. It happens in Chrome also.